# Valgrind Massif tool output graphical interface?

Tags: valgrind, massif

I'm using Valgrind 3.3.1 with the **Massif** tool to profile the heap of a C++ application, and I'm wondering if there is a **graphical tool** to examine the textual outputfile file.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 118):

For anyone else who is still interested in graphical output of Massif from Valgrind please consider [massif-visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer), it is beautiful.

[image]

You can find the project page at [KDE-Apps](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=122409).

For Ubuntu you should build massif-visualizer from [source](http://josh.gourneau.com/blog/2010/07/29/massif-visualizer-ubuntu-install-notes/) or install package from [Kubuntu-ppa](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/kubuntu-ppa_backports?dist=trusty) repo:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
apt-get update && apt-get install massif-visualizer
```

Comment: Links to the git repo seem to be out of date.

Comment: @Catskul - Looks like it has a 'proper' page on KDE-Apps with current links, edited to point there instead.

Comment: Its really hard to build it if you are running Centos... like, really, hard. Even installing KDE is not enough and some libraries need to be pulled as sources from ubuntu repos. Though the app is worth all the trouble

Comment: I'm going to sound like a dinosaur here, but Slackware 14.1, clone + follow the instructions in the INSTALL and it worked.

Comment: if you have some thing like `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)` please use **sudo** before each command. For the second one, add sudo at the beginning and **also** after the &&.

Comment: @Zeks: [I don't suppose you remember _what_ libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49340691/560648)

Comment: I can try to see tomorrow if bash history still remembers on that machine. This VM isn't used often so it might just be the case

Comment: In ubuntu 18.04 `massif-visualizer` is aviable from main repos.

Comment: Good tool, but it doesn't show the stack usage plot.

Answer (score 12):

I just made my own in-browser massif visualizer, since the available visualizers and viewers didn't compile on the platform I use.

So [take a look to it](http://boutglay.com/massifjs), it's online.

Answer (score 7):

There is a Qt application called massiftool that does a fair job of displaying this data.
Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/massiftool/ to see the project page.