# A decent GUI for valgrind? (massif outputs)

Tags: c++, valgrind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Valgrind Massif tool output graphical interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623771/valgrind-massif-tool-output-graphical-interface)

i was wondering if someone could point me to a good UI for valgrind? I'm especially interested in something that can visualize massif outputs. There is the valkyrie software in the ubuntu repo, but it says does not show massif outputs.

As you might have guessed, I'm developing software using c++ on ubuntu.

Thanks a lot,
Mohammad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623771/valgrind-massif-tool-output-graphical-interface

Comment: thanks so much. I should've first looked more closely ... my bad.

Comment: Check an online tool I just made http://boutglay.com/massifjs/