# how can I see how much memory my program is eating?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory

my program is running and creating variables, I need to know what's the total of Bytes these variables take.

I don't want to know how much is the physical memory space that the system gives my program to be executed, I know I can open the processes manager and find out.
I neither want to write into my code some sizeof and agregations so I can know the total size of the variable pool (let say the code is too complex to be modify like that).
Finally I'm using Microsoft VC++ 2010 Express, I just want to know if there is a workspace which monitor that kind of information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out: [Memory Performance Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . There are few metrics of a running process you might be interested in, you will primarily want `private bytes`, and this data is available both programmatically or through tools like `Performance Monitor`. You can also enumerate heaps of the process with [`GetProcessHeaps`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and even [`HeapWalk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you need details) and check heap allocation sizes directly.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind Massif profiler is a great tool (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623771/valgrind-massif-tool-output-graphical-interface) ) but only for Unix/Linux I think. In your case, on Windows I think [Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/insure.jsp;jsessionid=aaa64FpgN7GBiF?itemId=63) or [softwareverify](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php) are good choices (they are commercial tools).

A free alternative is  Google's tcmalloc which provides a heap profiler [here](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/)