# measuring functions memory usage in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, memory, benchmarking

I am using someone's code. It's a mess with a terrible coding style, weird function and variable names, and tones of macros, etc. My main concern is to find the function that loads things from disk to the memory. This function will drastically change the memory peak of the program. Now I am wondering if there is any tool that can provide me a list of functions with the memory consumption of each.

Comment: How is the memory consumption of a function defined?

Comment: A decent profiler will give you a good overview of which functions are taking CPU time and allocating memory.

Comment: Then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623771/valgrind-massif-tool-output-graphical-interface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use valgrind tool `massif`.

Massif is a heap profiler. I believe it is exactly what you need!

Simply start with:

```
valgrind --tool=massif <your prog>
ms_print massif.out.<your pid>
```

Detailed example and help can be found here:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.anexample

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux then Valgrind is tool for this.