# Building massif-visualizer: include could not find load file CMakeFindDependencyMacro

Tags: cmake, centos, valgrind, centos7, massif

I am attempting to build [massif-visualizer](https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer) on CentOS 7. Unfortunately I'm having to try to guess at dependencies as they are not all listed in the `INSTALL` file. So far:

```
yum install git
yum install kdelibs-devel extra-cmake-modules \
            qt5-qtsvg-devel qt5-qtxmlpatterns-devel \
            kf5-kparts-devel kf5-karchive-devel
git clone https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer
cd massif-visualizer
mkdir build
(cd build && cmake .. && make && make install)
```

Those Qt5 and KF5 packages were added to the `yum` command largely by trial and error, and some pattern-matching from CMake error messages … but I cannot seem to figure out how to resolve these last errors:

```
-- Could not set up the appstream test. appstreamcli is missing.
CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/KF5Archive/KF5ArchiveConfig.cmake:37 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CMakeFindDependencyMacro
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)


CMake Error at /usr/lib64/cmake/KF5Archive/KF5ArchiveConfig.cmake:38 (find_dependency):
  Unknown CMake command "find_dependency".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/find-modules/FindKF5.cmake:74 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)
```

Is this because, on CentOS 7, CMake (2.8.12.2) is too old? Or something else?

Comment: CMake 2.7.12.2 is actually **too old** for almost any feature about config/find packages. It looks like at least 3.0 version is required for `CMakeFindDependencyMacro` module.

Comment: My mistake - it's 2.8.12.2 :)

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thank you :) Have converted to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, CMake 2.8.12.2 is too old. Use CMake 3 instead:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install cmake3

(cd build && cmake3 .. && make && make install)
#                 ^
```

Now the installation complains about KChart but that's a separate issue.

---

In the end, here are my complete steps:

```
yum install epel-release
yum install subversion git cmake3 tar wget
yum install boost boost-devel
yum install kdelibs-devel extra-cmake-modules \
   graphviz-devel kdepim-devel \
   qt5-qtsvg-devel qt5-qtxmlpatterns-devel \
   kf5-kparts-devel kf5-karchive-devel \
   kf5-kiconthemes-devel kf5-kdoctools-devel
git clone https://github.com/KDE/massif-visualizer
wget https://download.kde.org/stable/kgraphviewer/2.4.0/kgraphviewer-2.4.0.tar.xz
wget https://download.kde.org/stable/kdiagram/2.6.0/src/kdiagram-2.6.0.tar.xz
tar xf kgraphviewer-2.4.0.tar.xz
tar xf kdiagram-2.6.0.tar.xz

for DIR in kgraphviewer-2.4.0 kdiagram-2.6.0 massif-visualizer
do
   cd $DIR
   mkdir build
   (cd build && cmake3 .. && make && make install)
   cd -
done
```

Then `valgrind --tool=massif myApp` and finally `massif-visualiser massif.out.<PID>` from a terminal inside a KDE session.

Comment: You also need `boost-devel` installed (and possibly `boost`)